# Comparing vectors for inequality use only equality operator on the vector elements. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11

Both my compilers (g++ and clang) won't compile this:

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
  friend bool operator!=(A const& a1, A const& a2) { return false; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> v1, v2;
  return (v1 != v2);
}
```

The error being that `!(*__first1 == *__first2)` somewhere in stl_algobase.h is invalid.

In other words, it is completely ignoring the existing operator!= of `A`.
Needless to say that if I define an `operator==` then it compiles and works.

Is this how it should be according to the standard?

If so, why?

Comment: Overloads for op== and op!= are independent, and none will be defined automatically. The standard-library-writers made the sensible decision to only use one of them, and providing the other in terms of that for users.

Comment: `a != b` on standard containers is specified to be equivalent to `!(a == b)`, and `a == b` is specified as `std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end())`, which is specified to use `==` for comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because [the comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) want an `EqualityComparable` or `LessThanComparable` type.

With only `==` and `<`, you can derive equivalent `!=`, `<=`, `>=`, and `>`. In other words, by only implementing 2 operators, you can get all 6 comparisons (assuming I haven't made a mistake in the logic):

```
(a != b) is !(a == b)
(a <= b) is !(b < a)
(a >= b) is !(a < b)
(a >  b) is  (b < a)
```

Standard containers use this usually, and will use `operator==` and `operator<` when doing comparisons for types.

So yes, this is as it should be.

As for the second part of the question (the *why*), I'm actually not entirely sure *why* the other operators aren't used if available.

Comment: Now, if you explained why the others are not automatically synthesised... then this might become a good answer.

Comment: You might as well fix `>=` while you're at it. The usual way to implement these operators can be seen in [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp). Not that anyone actually uses `rel_ops`...

Comment: @Deduplicator: I've added arguments; is that better?

Comment: I don't think that `<=` and `>=` will *ever* use `==`, that would be just wrong. I'll take the liberty to edit your answer to remove that.